# python input variable handling

Tags: python, fabric

trying to use input variable inside statement.

```
def email(account):
    email = fabric.operations.prompt("Enter client's email address:")
    run('mysql -u %s -p%s -e "UPDATE users SET email = %email WHERE id = 1" %s' % (env.user, dbpasswd, account))
```

Error:

```
  File "/tmp/fabfile.py", line 196, in email
    run('mysql -u %s -p%s -e "UPDATE users SET email = %email WHERE id = 1" %s' % (env.user, dbpasswd, account))
TypeError: float argument required, not str
```

any idea!

Comment: `%email` this should be your problem

Comment: embrace your parameters by str()

Comment: any example how? while declaration of variable? how?

Comment: If you run this command, any user that can view process information (can run `ps`) will know your mysql password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%email` this should be your problem,

string replacement encounters `%e` in `%email` before the last %s

```
In [4]: a = "1.2"

In [5]: print "%s" %a
1.2

In [6]: print "%e" %a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Python27\<ipython-input-6-1d66dedeb226> in <module>()
----> 1 print "%e" %a

TypeError: float argument required, not str
```

the simplest work around would be :

```
cmd = 'mysql -u %s -p%s -e "UPDATE users SET email = ' %(env.user, dbpasswd) + '%email' + ' WHERE id = 1" %s' %account

run(cmd)
```

or you could also do

```
data = "%email"
run('mysql -u %s -p%s -e "UPDATE users SET email = %s WHERE id = 1" %s' % (env.user, dbpasswd, data, account))
```

Comment: somehow its not returning variable value. output:

run: mysql -u root -ppassword -e "UPDATE users SET email = %email WHERE id = 1" demo

out: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%email WHERE id = 1' at line 1

Comment: try to print the cmd, and run it manually, see if manually sql query is working properly.. your `email` comes from `email = fabric.operations.prompt("Enter client's email address:")` this statement, check if it is proper

Comment: Enter client's email address: ghafil@xyz.com
mysql -u root -password -e "UPDATE users SET email = %email WHERE id = 1" demo

Done.

Comment: do you get proper output when you manually execute this sql query `mysql -u root -password -e "UPDATE users SET email = %email WHERE id = 1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14675/discussion-between-avasal-and-jahil)

Answer (score 1):

As said by avasal, the %email is your problem. Even if you can escape the '%' character by writing it '%%', starting from Python 2.6, I encourage you [to use the new format()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) syntax, so you can pass it to Python 3 without any changes :

```
>>> template = 'mysql -u {} -p{} -e "UPDATE users SET email = %email WHERE id = 1" {}'
>>> query = template.format("user", "pass", "account")
>>> print(query)
mysql -u user -ppass -e "UPDATE users SET email = %email WHERE id = 1" account
>>> run(query)
```

In addition, separating template from arguments helps to avoid code duplication, which is a good practice, and can save you lot of time.